# When a question is no longer what the user needs

Tags: discussion, answers

I recently participated in answering [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34252483/yii2-widgets-view/34252867#34252867) question. After a chat session with the OP it became apparent that what he was trying to do was not appropriate for his use case, and we arrived at a solution that better met his needs. My problem now is that the answer I posted no longer answers to the original question. It's been accepted as the correct answer, but from the point of view of Stack Overflow being a repository of knowledge, anyone searching for this question is not going to find an answer here.

Should I leave the question and my answer in case anyone is trying to do the same thing? They might also realise that it's not appropriate for them, or should I ask the OP to delete the question and re-ask it so I can post my relevant answer?

Comment: Related http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Exactly that, except that in this case I did know how to do Y, it just  seemed like overkill for his situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As yours is the **only answer** you (or the OP) can modify the question to match the (accepted) answer.

If there were other answers that answer the existing question then of course the question should not be modified. If it were, then it would (could) make those answers wrong, and adversely affect the reputation of those who answered.